# Is there an example of compact nonorientable $n$-manifold s.t. $H^i(M)\cong H_{n-i}(M)$ fails?

Tags: algebraic-topology

Is there an example of compact nonorientable $n$-manifold s.t. $H^i(M)\cong H_{n-i}(M)$ fails ?

Comment: Presumably you mean nonorientable, not unoriented.

Comment: @anomaly thanks, I have fixed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take $M = \mathbb{RP}^2$. It's compact, being a quotient of $S^2$, but it's easy to show that $H_1(M) = \mathbb{Z}_2$ and $H^1(M) = 0$.

Answer (score 4):

Every connected compact nonorientable manifold is a counterexample.  Indeed, $H_n(M)=0$ and $H^0(M)=\mathbb{Z}$ for any such $M$, giving a counterexample with $i=0$.

Comment: Can you explain, why in this case $H_n(M)=0$?

Comment: This is a nontrivial statement that is part of the theory of Poincare duality.  See, for instance, Theorem 3.26(b) in Hatcher.